# Como averiguar si cada caracter despues de la variable i de un for, es un numero, y si lo es agregar una coma al final

Tags: java, algoritmos

tengo lo siguiente:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) 
    {
       if(result.substring(i).matches("[0-9]+") && result.substring(i+1).matches("[0-9]+"))
       {
           result += ",";
       }
    }
```

lo que deseo hacer es que busque en un string si hay un caracter (signo) y lo separe de los digitos, lo que hace el codigo de arriba es  buscar en el string un numero y si el siguiente caracter es tambien un numero de 0 al 9 poner una coma para separarlo de los signos, pero el error esta en el hecho que solo sirve para 2 digitos y no 3 o 4 o mas eso es lo que quiero terminar haciendo gracias. 
Si no me explique bien o entendieron algo de lo que escribi por favor escribanmelo en los comentarios soy nuevo en esta plataforma igualmente muchas gracias !!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: podrias agregar un ejemplo de entrada y de la salida?

Comment: si disculpen si no esta muy clara mi explicación, estoy recientemente usando esta plataforma para poder resolver algunas de mis dudas, lo que el código de arriba hace es que busca en el String result por medio del for si el caracter es un numero y si el siguiente también si los son, pondra una coma y asi sucesivamente, lo que quiero es poder modificar ese codigo para poder no solo buscar el caracter y el siguiente sino que busque hasta encontrarse con algun caracter y que ahi recien ponga la coma, osea separe el numero (ya sea de 1, 2, 3 digitos ) y los otros caracteres que van a ser signos.

Comment: ok.. por eso te pedi un ejemplo, a veces con un par de ejemplos se explica mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

porque no anda tu codigo? porque substring esta mal usado. substring devuelve desde el string, hasta el final de la cadena. con lo cual, salvo que sean todos numeros, no va a devolver nada.

en este caso, conviene ir de a un caracter e ir marcando si el anterior era un numero o no.

```
String cadena = "123423-2132321-21-2223-21";
String resul = "";
Boolean esnumero = true;
for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length()-1; i++) 
{
   if(cadena.substring(i,i+1).matches("[0-9]+"))
   {
       esnumero = true;
       resul = resul + cadena.substring(i,i+1);
   }
   else if(esnumero)
   {
        esnumero = false;
        resul = resul + "," + cadena.substring(i,i+1);
   }
}
```

El codigo que te pase, itera la cadena de a un caracter por vez, agregandolo a una cadena resultado. y recordando si el ultimo es numero o no. si el anterior fue numero, pero este no, entonces pone una coma.

String.substring tiene dos formas de ser usado. En una, recibe un solo parametro, que es el indice desde donde tomar los datos, y toma desde ahi hasta el final de la cadena. En su otra version, de dos parametros, el primero es el indice de inicio, y el segundo el indice de fin para la cadena a ser devuelta.

Comment: muy buena tu explicación, recién me estoy familiarizando con algunos metodos de java y la verdad solamente habia leido el docs y no habia entendido muy bien, me podrías aclarar que es el primer dato que pasas al substring? entiendo que uno es el indice, que supongo es el segundo elemento pero el primero no se a q se refiere, en este caso cadena.substring(i , i+1), el primer valor i que vendria a ser? gracias de antemano

Comment: @KenjiMiyashiro ahi edite la respuesta

Comment: ok muchas gracias por aclararme la duda

Comment: Recuerda aceptar alguna de las respuestas una vez que solucionen tu problema. mira [tour] si no lo hiciste asi sabes como funcionamos..

Comment: gracias por recordarmelo

Answer (score 2):

Bueno, lo que entiendo es básicamente separar dígitos de no-digitos (letras/signos). Ya que estas intentando con expresiones regulares entonces la siguiente que busca patrones numéricos y no numéricos en cualquier orden puede servir:

```
String[] salida = result.split( "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)" );
System.out.println( String.join( ",", salida ) );
```

**Edito:**

- El meta-caracter `\d` Equivale a caracter numerico (digito).
- El meta-caracter `\D` Equivale a caracter no-numerico (letras, signos).

En la RegExp operador lógico `|` (or) logicamente nos sugiere que va a ejecutarse una acción u otra. Por un lado tenemos `(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)` donde `(?<=\\D)` (*Lookbehind Assertion*) nos va a indicar las coincidencias que están precedidas por un carácter no-numerico y `(?=\\d)` (*Lookahead Assertion*) no trae los patrones que están seguidos por un caracter numérico.

En la otra mano tenemos `(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)`, al desglosar veremos inversamente que `(?<=\\d)` (*Lookbehind Assertion*) nos consigue los patrones que están precedidos por un dígito y por ultimo `(?=\\D)` (*Lookahead Assertion*) devolverá las coincidencias seguidas por una letra.

De tal manera que si por ejemplo `String result = "+34/5+455-6*344343ABc232";` tendriamos como resultado:

> +,34,/,5,+,455,-,6,*,344343,ABc,232

Comment: disculpa me podrías explicar que significa ese regex del string salida? osea 
String[] salida = result.split( "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)" );  entiendo que el split separara el string por grupos dependioendo del dato que se le pase pero el regex no lo entiendo muy bien  ...

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta con una breve explicación acerca de esa regexp.

Comment: muchas gracias por aclararme las dudas

Comment: Buena respuesta. Cambiaría `\D` por `[^\d.]` para permitir decimales... Y ya que coincide con las posiciones, parecería más lógico usar `result.replaceAll( regex, "," )`.